# I want to fill a text field in a page with a variable taken from the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to know how I can get the last element of `$('span.srs');` and assign it to a variable. Then the variable is inserted into a text field with `$("input[name=Any]").val();`. Is that possible or there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[name=Any]").val($('span.srs:last').text());
```

Comment: Deleted my answer and upvoted yours, trying to teach you some sportsmanship.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote? Will take that anyways ..:) BTW what made you think that i have not enough sportsmanship..

Comment: @TheSuperTramp When I post an answer and find that someone posted exactly the same answer earlier (while I was writing), I delete my answer and upvote his. No need to have two of the same answer.

Comment: i also saw the other answers, but i thought our answers were different(essentially similar) so kept my answer. Anyways have a nice day..:)

Comment: @TheSuperTramp You should have a nice day too, and go Gunners :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var last = $('span.srs:last-child');
$("input[name=Any]").val(last.text());
```

Comment: This one seems more correct for the asked question, as it gets the last child of the span ... the other options above get the last span of that particular class ...

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're trying to get the last span.srs, or you want the last child. If it's the last child you are after, use the :last-child selector

Comment: Yes, the question was ambiguous. "The last element of $('span.srs');" can mean the last element of the jQuery collection, or the last child of the span. I think we should wait with our decisions until OP clarifies, I will delete my answer and upvote this if the `:last-child` is needed.